# await Task.Delay of over 15 ms doesn't wait long enough

Tags: c#, async-await, clock, system-clock

In troubleshooting a test that validated concurrency I discovered that some of our build machines (running in VMs) consistently report that tasks aren't waiting the full `Task.Delay` interval. To confirm, I wrote a test which creates a histogram of how many milliseconds from the requested delay it took.

On my machine, the results are as you'd expect:

```
interval ms => number of items completing in that interval
--
0 - 4 ms => 13 # 13 iterations completed within 4 ms of the requested delay
5 - 9 ms => 194
10 - 14 ms => 714
15 - 19 ms => 61
20 - 24 ms => 12
25 - 29 ms => 3
40 - 44 ms => 2
45 - 49 ms => 1
```

But on the build machine, the test reports that all of the tasks completed before the requested delay was completed:

```
-10 - -6 ms => 999
-5 - -1 ms => 1
```

Here's the test / histogram generator:

```
[Test]
[Timeout(60_000)]
public async Task TaskDelayAccuracyCheck()
{
  var results = new List<long>();
  for (var i = 0; i<1000; ++i)
  {
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    await Task.Delay(20);
    sw.Stop();
    results.Add((sw.ElapsedTicks - 20*10_000)/10_000);
  }
  var histo = results.GroupBy(t => t / 5).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
  foreach (var group in histo)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key*5} - {(group.Key+1)*5 - 1} ms => {group.Count()}");
  }
  Assert.Multiple(() =>
  {
    foreach (var group in histo)
    {
      Assert.That(group.Key, Is.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0));
    }
  });
}
```

The [Task.Delay documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8) says (emphasis added):

> This method depends on the system clock. This means that the time delay will approximately equal the resolution of the system clock if the delay argument **is less than the resolution of the system clock**, which is approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows systems.

In this case, I have ensured that the delay is not *less than* the 15 ms referred to above, and I've used the `Stopwatch` class to ensure the timings are as precise as possible. In addition, [Stopwatch.IsHighResolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution?view=netframework-4.8) returns `true`, so I should be able to trust the timings.

I have been operating under the presumption that the delay will always be at least the requested time, but could be longer by the resolution of the system clock. Should I infer instead that the delay will always be within the (system clock resolution) or roughly 15ms on Windows? Or, is something else going on?

Comment: Could there be environmental differences between the build server and your local machine?  You say that "some" build machines report these odd results - I presume some of your build machines are reporting perceived-correct results?

Comment: if you need an accurate "timer" you should always use a new thread, and use thread.sleep() if the delays are small (< 30 ms) and have to be accurate. If you're using tasks you are using the convenient route and are always at the mercy of the threadpool to give you a free thread when requested.

Comment: I believe your calculation involving the ElapsedTicks is incorrect. Can you explain where that calculation is coming from? It would be easier to use the stopwatch's Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.

Comment: What does `Stopwatch.Frequency` return, on the same machine? If it's not 10000000, then as others have said, your calculation is incorrect.

Comment: The code assumes that a tick is 100 nanoseconds, like it is for DateTime.  It is not.  Use Elapsed.Ticks instead.

Comment: I thought that all "High Resolution" timers had a frequency of 10,000,000, but that is indeed not the case resulting in my laziness catching up with me. I'm seeing a frequency of 2,438,582 on the build machine, with `IsHighResolution` set to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're measuring correctly.

You're assuming that there are always 10,000 ticks per millisecond. But that might not always be the case. You can look at [`Stopwatch.Frequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency) to see the ticks per *second* that it uses on the current system. That value is [set the first time `Stopwatch` is used](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,51) based on a call to the native Windows [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancefrequency) function.

Divide by 1000 to get ticks per millisecond.

```
var ticksPerMillisecond = Stopwatch.Frequency / 1000;
```

But you can even more easily just use the [`ElapsedMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds) property, which accurately [converts the ticks to milliseconds](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,124) for you.

```
results.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - 20);
```